# How do I handle an express route json error (without "Can't set headers after they are sent.")

Tags: express

I've got an Express route which uses `response.json` to return the response.  However, I can't figure out how to catch error cases with it.  If I do:

```
try {
   response.json();
} catch (e){
  response.send('it went wrong!'
}
```

or if I do:

```
.then(() => response.json())
.catch(() => response.send('it went wrong!')
```

I get a `Can't set headers after they are sent` error.

That makes sense, since `json` calls `end`, and you can't set headers after `end` is called.  However, if I can't edit the response after an error occurs in `json`, how can I possibly return an error response in such a case?

Comment: Just a head's up here. There are several methods in express that actually `end` the request (`res.json()`, `res.render()`). If you call `res.end` after any of these methods, you will see this error. So the question would be, how do you refactor your routing logic to prevent a `res.end` after any other response sent...

Comment: Yes exactly.  As I explained in the question, I do understand what's going on.  What I don't understand is how to work around what's going on so that I can return an error response when `json()` errors.

Comment: IMHO, the end of the response should not be part of your logic... can it be moved outside your `try` `catch` and moved to a `finally`?... you could create different jsons depending of the success or error of your logic and at the end just send that object with a message embedded. If you are using promises, same thing... your last `then` should be the one responding or your `catch` but should be the last clause of your logic or be completely out of it... Again, it's just an opinion, that is how I've solve this kind of issues before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

... Or you could always check:

```
if (!res.headerSent) {
 // do your stuff end with res.json(), res.end(), res.render() or whatever you need
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how that helps: the headers aren't sent until I call `.json()`, so checking whether they are set before doesn't help because a `json()` error will still be impossible to respond to.

Comment: ... the only reason that I could think on why the `.json()` call would fail is because it's executing logic within it or is sending a `json` string malformed... the other reason is because you have `res.*` before your `res.json` and the headers are set way before it... I'm suggesting a work around to the `res.send()` to inform the user ... but that implies logic change. Sorry It could not fit what you need... just trying to help :)

Comment: It turned out to be an issue with my logic after all, thanks.

Comment: :D glad that It helped :)